# Can't run .jsp pages directly

Tags: java, eclipse, jsp

I'm having a problem using eclipse that recently appeared. When I try to run any .jsp file i get the

> 404 error resource not available.

However if I run the .java file I get the page loaded up. executing the following java code I can get the page to run but it still wont redirect the page after the correct button is pressed. I get no other error messages other than the one I already mentioned.

```
protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {

    response.setContentType("text/html");

    String action = null, address = null;
    address = "/WEB-INF/PhonebookMain.jsp";
    action = (String) request.getParameter("action");

    if(action == null){
        action = "nema";
    }
    if(action == "nema"){       
    }else
    {
        if(action == "Unos"){
            address ="/WEB-INF/Unos.jsp";
        }

        if(action == "Izmjena"){
            address = "/WEB-INF/Izmjena.jsp";
        }

    }
    RequestDispatcher dispatcher = request.getRequestDispatcher(address);
    dispatcher.forward(request, response);
}
}
```

Comment: which IDE you are using NetBeans or Eclipse or other?

Comment: You're comparing Strings with ==. Use equals(). http://stackoverflow.com/questions/513832/how-do-i-compare-strings-in-java

Answer (score 4):

It's not a bug, it's a feature. All resources under WEB-INF are, by specification, inaccessible from the outside, because that's where your classes, configuration, etc., which should stay private, reside.

People typically put their JSPs under WEB-INF precisely because JSPs are views, and should thus never be executed directly: all the requests should first go to a controller, which then forwards to a view. That seems to be what you're doing here: the servlet is a controller which dispatches to a view. So executing the JSP directly doesn't make much sense: the request should go through the controller first.

Comment: OK that makes sense, however I still can't get the views to change after I press the buttons in the form.

Comment: You're comparing strings with ==. Use equals().

Comment: Thanks everything is working now, you helped a lot ^^

Answer (score 0):

remove the `/WEB-INF` from `url`and use `/something.jsp` then try

if you have all `.jsp` files inside `web-inf folder` copy them from there and paste them directly under `web-content` folder